# Passing data (transactionId) to CXF interceptors

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, interceptor

I trying to build an UI to view the SOAP transactions that were sent out from my application.

A typical scenario is that each user transaction include multiple web-service request to multiple systems and I am generating a transactionId for that user transaction and Logging all the logs with that transactionId in log file, so that the log file can be searched using the transactionId and the corrosponding log statements can be displayed on UI.

So, I am able to append the generated transactionId to all the log statements and able to pull them from log files.

But the issue is that for the SOAP request, I am unable to figure out a way to to add the same transactionId in the log file in SOAP request.

Can someone provide me some pointers how can I pass the generated transactionId to  CXF interceptors ( or custom CXF interceptors)  so that when the CXF logs the SOAP request and repsonse it will append the passed transactionId.

Like this

```
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
transactionId=1234ABCXXX
ID: 1
Address: http://localhost:8080/Zservice/get?wsdl
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=[""]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:get xmlns:ns2="http://service.zservice.com/"><arg0/></ns2:get></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am finally able to active this using MDC

In your web-service adapter where you are invoking the web-service client set the transaction Id in MDC like this.

```
      MDC.put("transaction", transId);        
      Account acct= new Account();
       //Set the requrest 

      //invoke WS client
      client.get(acct);
```

In your custom interceptors, retrieve the transaction Id

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) {

    String transaction = MDC.get("transaction");

    logger.info("Transaction ID: {} ", transaction);
    try {

         LogInUtil.logging(logger, message, transaction);
         }
        catch (Exception ex) {
           logger.warn("Unable to save SOAP Response due to {}",ex.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a unique transaction-id for each request in order to associate it with the request, you need to get hold of the `org.apache.cxf.message.Message` instance. It is passed as parameter to all interceptors in the `handleMessage()` method. You can also use `org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()` in static context to get hold of it anywhere in your application.

You can then create the transaction-id in `InInterceptor` as in

```
Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
message.put("transaction-id",UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

In your code where you are logging the SOAP request/response you can retrieve and log it

```
Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
String transactionId = message.get("transaction-id");
// happy logging
```

Comment: I don't want to generate the Transaction Id inside the interceptor. I already  have a transaction Id generated which I need to pass to the interceptors so that when it logs the ws request and response , it also appends the passed transaction Id to the ws logs.

Comment: I was able to achive this using MDC. I will add the solution