# CXF 3.0.4 SOAP client interceptors pass parameters

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, interceptor

I'm using CXF 3.0.4 and I like to pass some parameters to outbound intercptors (or outbound chain) before calling soap client. I found this question [Passing data (transactionId) to CXF interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347989/passing-data-transactionid-to-cxf-interceptors) but isn't there some cleaner solution how to stay with CXF only?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to pass parameters to interceptor before client call like this:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(targetClient);
client.getRequestContext().put("my-object", myObject);
```

Basically you only need to wrap your port with **org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client** and then put parameter to requestContext

and in Interceptor just get parameter like this:

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {    
    Object obj = message.get("my-object");
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is not per message I assume. How about if I want to pass data that is per message?